# How to calculate powers of complex numbers in Python without using the complex numbers data type

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, complex-numbers

I'm wondering how I can calculate powers of a complex number without using the complex numbers data type. So I have a function

```
def Power_complex(re, im, n):
```

How can I calculate (re + im * i)^n with this? Thank you!

Comment: Do you know how to do that by hand? If not, go learn that first. If you do know, then what trouble are you having with getting a computer to do the same thing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in Python I would have to use math.atan2(im, re). Mulitply that by n. Take it's sin and cos to get coordinates. And then print(Re*x, '+', Im*y, 'i')

But that's not working unfortunately :/

Comment: Nope, that's not how complex exponentiation works. Try implementing it in angle-and-magnitude representation instead of coordinate representation, then write code to convert between representations.

Comment: Or, if you only need to handle integer `n`, try implementing it in terms of complex multiplication.

Comment: if you know how to multiply two complex number, you know how to get any (integer) power on them

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the Biniomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) for arbitrary exponents, although positive integers is the easiest case.

Or you can treat the problem in [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Computing_complex_powers) (this link simply gives you the answer, only click if you really don't want to figure it out on your own)

Comment: I know about the complex powers with the polar form. I just don't have a clue how to implement it in Python

Comment: @Yusif The second wikipedia link in my post provides a formula for performing the calculation, in terms of cosine, sine, natural log, and natural exponentiation. That's what you need.